# Angular2 recursive tree expand all

Tags: recursion, angular, treeview

I have recursive tree component and I would like to expand all nodes on click from parent component, how can I do this? More details in plunker.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Q5obfcW1mhsYe9jFXZo?p=preview)

I talking about this method:

```
   expandAll(){
    console.log("expanded all");
  }
```

Comment: Your plunker is empty, the only component in it is not a recursive one.

Comment: Im so sorry, try to check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I guess I figure it out. I just added one more `@Input()` in `TreeComponent`:

```
@Input() expandAll: boolean;
```

and replaced `*ngIf` recursive condition to:

```
[hidden]="(!expanded[i] && !expandAll) || (expanded[i] && expandedAll)"
```

Its need a bit more work (collapsing all doesnt work that how it should), but it works that how I wanted.

[Plnker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5Q5obfcW1mhsYe9jFXZo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `expandAll()` method to the `TreeComponent` that expands all nodes and calls `expandAll()` on all nested `TreeComponent` components.

You can get all nested `TreeComponent` components by adding

```
@ViewChildren(TreeComponent) subTrees:QueryList<TreeComponent>;
```

and call the method on the childs like

```
expandAll() {
  for(var subTree of this.subTrees.toArray()) {
    subTree.expandAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I call in app component method from parent TreeComponent?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your comment means. From how I understand your question, this is what my answer should explain.

Comment: This is what you meant https://plnkr.co/edit/5Q5obfcW1mhsYe9jFXZo?p=preview, right? And how can I call expandAll of parent tree component from app component?

Comment: I show 2 ways in https://plnkr.co/edit/gYHzyBf8EEF9Cxn5sUR3?p=preview (one is view only, the other with the 2nd pair of buttons is using `@ViewChild()`)

Comment: Its look like your plnkr doesnt work (buttons) for me, did you saved your final version?

Comment: The first `Collapse all` doesn't work because this method is not implemented in the tree component. The others "work" by printing to the console.

Comment: But anyway its doesnt work, check that after click expand all, you will get only once printed "expand all". Shouldnt it be called from all subtrees?

Comment: Actually this doesn't work in your case because when `expanded[i]` is false the tree-component just doesn't exist (`subTrees` is empty) and you can't call methods on it. You can either use `[hidden]="!expanded[i]"` instead or set expanded for all items, run `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` (`ChangeDetectorRef` can be injected) and then call `expandAll()` on all child tree components.